# Electric field is produced by the changing magnetic field and not by charged particles according to coulomb's law or Gauss's law?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electric-fields, electromagnetic-induction

In my physics textbook, *Concept of physics* by H.C. Verma, in the section on "Induced electric field", the statement below is written (p. 291):

> Electric field is produced by the changing magnetic field and not by charged particles according to Coulomb's law or Gauss's law.

I cannot understand this statement. Can anyone kindly explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Electrostatic field is described by the Coulomb law or the Gauss law.

Induced electric field is a different kind of electric field, not described by the Coulomb law or the Gauss law. Instead, it is described by Faraday's law of electromagnetic induction. Qualitatively, whenever magnetic field changes in time, induced electric field appears.

Induced electric field is still due to charged particles, it is stronger closer to the charged particles creating it, but is present only when their magnetic field is changing in time. This happens, for example, when isolated charged body moves uniformly (the charged body passing by produces time-dependent magnetic field and induced electric field) or when current in a circuit changes in time (then its magnetic field changes in time and thus there is also induced electric field).

Comment: Induced electric field is still due to charged particles , But sir , professor said that induced electric field is present even in absence of material if there is time varying magnetic field. So, how induced field is present there ?

Comment: That is a mathematical possibility (EM field without a source), but in practice, some source of that changing magnetic field can be identified, and that is also source of the induced electric field.

Comment: For the textbook plane electromagnetic wave, there is no source. This is a decent approximation of a real electromagnetic wave in many circumstances. But it's not physically possible: without a source you have no wave. Note that physical theory always involves unstated approximations: everything your professor teaches is untrue in some sense. What he really means here by absence of material is that the material source of the field is so far away that it may be neglected for the purpose of modeling of the fields.

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

I recommend Jefimenko's Eqs, and discussion there-in: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jefimenko%27s_equations

I this formulation, $\vec E$ and $\vec B$ at a point/time are entirely determined by charges, currents, and their time derivatives on the past light cone.

There is no induction, since $\dot{\vec B}$ doesn't create $\vec E$; rather, it is proportional to $\nabla \times \vec E$ as a result of the symmetries of the source equation (which are less apparent than in Maxwell's formulation).

Light is no longer a self propagating wave, either. Instead, it is the fields of distant sources moving away at the speed of causality.